# Create new column based on condition from one column and the value from another column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DF with time given as hours, minutes or milliseconds.
The time column has the type float and the time_unit column indicate if it is given as hour, minute or ms.

I want to create a a new column that calculates the amount of seconds. Thus, I need a function that first checks what time_unit it is, then takes the value from time and performs some transformation to seconds.

For example:

```
if df["time_unit"]="h":
   return df["time"]*60*60 # given hours as int
elseif: ...
```

My df looks like this:

[image]

I want to create the green column (seconds). So, how do I do this in pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create the mapping `dict`

```
d = {'h' : 60*60, 'min' : 60, 'ms' : 1/1000}

df['seconds'] = df['time_unit'].map(d) * df['time']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
seconds = []
for i,r in df.iterrows():
  if r['time_unit'] == 'h':
    seconds.append(r['time']*3600)
  elif r['time_unit'] == 'min':
    seconds.append(r['time']*60)
  elif r['time_unit'] == 'ms':
    seconds.append(r['time']/1000)
df['seconds'] = seconds
```

I guess this will work.

Comment: I tried something similar, but apply it as a function. df["seconds"] = df.apply(func...). I got some warning: "SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame."
How could I apply this solution as a function on a df?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).